# VBA end a sub early without ending sub subs

Tags: vba

Sub A calls Sub B and within Sub B I have it End under certain conditions. My desired result is that Sub A finishes it's operation but Sub B ending causes Sub A to end as well. What is the proper way to preemptively end a sub without having it close out the parent sub calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send program control back to the caller using `Exit Sub`